# .indexOf() is not a function error with external json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What I currently have in my .json file:

```
{
  "cat": {
    "gender": "male"
  },
  "dog": {
    "gender": "female"
  }
}
```

What I tried using:

```
const animals = require('../../data/animals.json');

var Animal = animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)]; // Lets say it returns dog //

var index = animals.indexOf(Animal); // Tries to get the index number of the dog

console.log(index); // Expected Output: "1"
```

However it returns:

> indexOf is not a function

How do I fix this? Thank you~

Comment: `animals` is an object not an array. `Animal` will be `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript the subscript operator `[]` works on both objects and arrays.  Line 2 will result in `Animal` being undefined.  Since `animals` is an object it will not have the member function of an array.  You could use `Object.values(animals)` to produce an array of all values in `animals`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the keys first and then a random index.

```js
var animals = { cat: { gender: "male" }, dog: { gender: "female" } },
    keys = Object.keys(animals),
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);

console.log(keys);
console.log(index);
console.log(animals[keys[index]]);
```